# kcs-evdefer and kworker suddenly appeared and consumed high CPU usage

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, cpu-usage

This process (kcs-evdefer/[0-3] and kworker) suddenly appeared and consumed high CPU

[image]

What services is that? and how to manage it? Thank you

Comment: k-worker it seems to be the kernel thread workload which perform most of the kernel works. but i don't have an idea about kcs-evdefer.

Comment: i read from internet that kcs-evdefer is like Falcon crowdstrike in cloud (the instance i use is in AWS cloud), CMIIW. Any idea about that?